# How to display comments "Duplicate comment detected" error message in same page

Tags: wordpress, validation, comments

I developing a site. In comments page, all the validation errors messages are shown in new page instead of same page. So I used jQuery validation plug-in for empty fields, and it is working perfectly. But I could not solve "Duplicate comment detected" error message to same page. Can any one help me to resolve this problem. Thanks in advance.